# How can I fix the Xbox 360 error code 03-57-00?

Tags: xbox-360

I got this error code `03-57-00` on one of my Xbox 360 games, but all my other games work fine. The disc looks a little scratched up. I have tried Microsoft's suggestions, and cleaned it with a solvent. Is there any way to fix the disc or should I replace it?

Answer (score 1):

Error **03-57-00** occurs on Xbox 360
You see the following error code and message when you’re using your Xbox 360 console:

**03-57-00** --
Unrecognized Disc

This could mean one of the following things:

- There’s a problem with the disc (for example, it might be scratched or dirty).
- The game you’re trying to play has known problems.

**Solutions**:
 1. [Xbox 360 Disc Drive Solution](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/system/disc-drive-solution)
 2. [Device Support](https://devicesupport.microsoft.com/)

(This was taken from the [xbox support website](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/errors/error-code-03-57-00))